# FIFO Communication between two different process c++

Tags: c++, process, fifo

Hi please some one help me

I've two process say some X and Y.
X and Y both have the following information

```
typedef enum {
    HEALTHY=1,
    FAULTY=2,
    CHANGE=3,
    ERROR=4
} MsgTypeT;

typedef struct {
    char role[16];
    char state[16];
    char info[256];
} InfoT;

typedef struct {
    MsgTypeT type;
    int size;
    InfoT *data;
} MsgT;
```

Here the condition is that if process Y sends an information process X will read it
So i used fifo between x and y
Y has a function write buffer which writes to fifo and code is as following

```
int write_buffer(HA_DEVMON_MsgT const* send)
{                   
char* dest = buffer;
memcpy( dest, &send->type, sizeof( MsgTypeT ));
dest += sizeof(MsgTypeT);
memcpy( dest, &send->size, sizeof( int ));
dest += sizeof(int);
memcpy( dest, send->data, sizeof( InfoT ));
dest += sizeof(InfoT);
int byteCount = write( this->fifo_fd, buffer, dest - buffer );
if ( byteCount != dest - buffer ) {
cout<<"Error in writing ";
}
return byteCount == dest - buffer ? 0 : -1;
}
```

I think it's writing perfectly because cout statements are working fine also when tried to output nbytes it gave 512bytes have been written

Now when X tries to read it's giving null values for role and state also size its giving 6441568
Its only giving MsgTypeT correct other values are null :(
The code is as follows--- I'm doing something wrong please correct it

```
int readMsg(MsgT *msg)
{
    int rCode=0, nbytes=0;
    char buffer[512]={0};

    nbytes = read(this->get_handle(), buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (nbytes < 0) {
        cout<<"error in read";
        rCode=-1;
    } 
    if (rCode == 0) {
        char *p_src = (char *)buffer;
        mempcpy(&msg->type, p_src, sizeof(MsgTypeT));
        p_src+=sizeof(MsgTypeT);
        mempcpy(&msg->size, p_src, sizeof(int));
        p_src+=sizeof(int);
        msg->data = new InfoT(); //allocating memory (needed or not???)
        mempcpy(msg->data, p_src, sizeof(InfoT));
        p_src+=sizeof(InfoT);
    }
    return rCode;
}
```

Comment: I think char buffer[512]={0}; just sets the first element of buffer to 0, which has nothing to do with the question. Just saying.

Comment: @doctorlove: actually, `char buffer[512]={0};` is a common (but maybe not obvious) way to initialize the complete array in C and C++

Comment: I guess you best chance of finding what is going wrong is using a debugger.

Comment: @ stefaanv : Y i'm unable to decode the contents of data and how to debug it

Answer (score 2):

In `readMsg`, your last `mempcpy` writes to `msg`, not to the
`InfotT` you just allocated.

Also, but I suppose you know this: this is only guaranteed to
work if both processes were compiled with the same compiler,
using the same options.  (In practice, it's likely to work if
the underlying system defines its API in terms of C, which is
the case for Windows and Unix.)

EDIT:

Further: you have the same problem when writing.  You write
`sizeof(InfoT)` (288) bytes, but you write the pointer (and then
a lot of garbage), not the data it's pointing to.

And you increment the pointer into the `MsgT` object.  This is
likely not to work, if there is any padding.  What you really
have to do is:

```
int
write_buffer( MsgT const* data )
{
    char buffer[512] = {};  //  Or better yet, std::vector<char>
    char* dest = buffer;
    memcpy( dest, &data->type, sizeof( MsgTypeT ) );
    dest += sizeof( MsgTypeT );
    memcpy( dest, &data->size, sizeof( int ) );
    dest += sizeof( int );
    memcpy( dest, &data->data, sizeof( InfoT ) );
    dest += sizeof( InfoT );
    int byteCount = write( fifo_fd, buffer, dest - buffer );
    if ( byteCount != dest - buffer ) {
        std::cerr << "Error in write" << std::endl;
    }
    return byteCount == dest - buffer ? 0 : -1;
}
```

and the opposite when reading.

And once again, this will only really work for two processes on
the same machine, compiled with the same compiler using the same
options.  A better solution would probably be to define
a protocol, with a defined representation of integers, strings,
etc., format your output to that representation, and parse it
for your input.  That way, it will still work even if one of the
processes is 64 bits, and the other 32.

Comment: @James Kanze : Compiled with same compiler and same options and on unix platform I use a generic makefile

Comment: In theory, everything must be the same.  In practice, there are probably `struct` in the system API, which means that all compilers will lay them out in a compatible way.

Comment: @ James Kanze : Now the size in read is 288 but still some garbage and null values in contents of data while reading.... Can you help me correct the read code...i'm using the same code given above

Comment: @PhaninderGattu Have you made the corresponding changes in the read routine? Also, how do you fill the initial `InfoT`?  If you're using something like `strcpy`, it likely will contain garbage values in each field, after the terminating `'\0'`.  These will be copied and read, but don't matter, because on the receiving end, you shouldn't actually use any of the `char` after the `'\0'`.

Comment: @ James Kanze I've edited the post of read code correct me if something is wrong and i'm filling the values using strcpy in role and state.... By the way i'm not getting garbage values i'm getting empty or null string

Comment: @PhaninderGattu Have you also changed the read code to use the field names, rather than just incrementing the destination pointer?  It's quite possible that `MsgTypeT` has a size of 1, and that there are three bytes padding between `type` and `size`.

Comment: @ James Kanze I'm not getting your point about using the field names if you could write it down i will say whether i tried or not if not i will try now.. I'm helpless and out of thoughts ... also no change of approach as its not in my hands i should make this code work... I previously dealt with these type of codes but struggling now

Comment: @PhaninderGattu For starters, make sure you're reading the same number of bytes as you're writing.  And there's an error in my code (and probably in yours): when reading and writing the data, you shouldn't take the address, because it is a pointer, and it is what is pointed to that we want to read and write.

Comment: @ James Kanze : Thanks came to know about the problem now everything is working fine :) Edited the code and thanks for all